# Whats the best way to implement this service/controller pattern?

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, promise

In my nodejs/express rest api im using the service/controller pattern.
In the service im calling to mongodb. I want the error handling/throwing to happen in the service, but i dont want co call `User.find()` twice.

controller.js

```
exports.findAll = (req, res, next) => {
    userService.findAllUsers()
        .then(users => res.json(users))
        .catch(err => next(err));
};
```

service.js

```
async function findAllUsers() {
    if(await User.find()) {
        return await User.find()
    } else {
        throw "Couldn't retrieve all users"
    }
}
```

How would I have to rewrite the service function, to be able to throw an error if `User.find()` fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store it in a variable:

```
async function findAllUsers() {
    let users = await User.find();
    if(users) {
        return users;
    } else {
        throw "Couldn't retrieve all users"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But wouldn't this lead to an unhandled promise rejection if `User.find()` fails?

Comment: I'm just following your original logic. In your original logic you don't have a try/catch block so this has the exact same meaning as your original code

Comment: If you want to catch errors you can add a try/catch block but you are throwing an error anyway so I don't understand your complaint about promise rejection failure since your `throw` will also result in promise rejection failure if not caught

Comment: Besides, you are already handling promise errors in `.catch(err => next(err))`

Comment: The problem is that the error in `.catch(err => next(err))` is returned directly by the api. I dont want the mongoose error to be spit out by my api but rather catch the mongoose error and throw a new error with a custom, user friendly error message

Answer (score 0):

### use try catch

```
async function findAllUsers() {
    try {
        return await User.find();
    } catch(error) {
        return error;
    }
}
```

Comment: This changes the logic of the original code. It will 1. not handle null return value as error and 2. break his `.catch()`

Answer (score 0):

## Use following :

```
// # service.js
async function findAllUsers() {
    // # return with new promise.
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return await User.find().then(user => resolve(user)).error(er => reject(er));
    });
}
```

For more ref, clone this repo : https://github.com/sagormax/node-admin